# Declaring multiple event handlers does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, event-handling

I have a page that can contain multiple user controls. Each user control has at least one button that invokes an event. I want to capture these events.

I produced a test page - the results are that a single handler explicity set on the user control works, however a ForEach does not. Here's the code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This works
        JumpButton1.HasVisited += new EventHandler(JumpButton_HasVisited);

        // This does not work            
        this.Controls.OfType<JumpButton>()
        .ForEach(uc => uc.HasVisited += new EventHandler(JumpButton_HasVisited));
    }

    void JumpButton_HasVisited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Updated button: " + DateTime.Now;
    }
```

For information when I count the controls returned - a count of 1 is returned which would indicate that the controls are being found.

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

---

### UPDATE 1

Here is an example using my own extension method to find the controls. I added a check to see if jumGroup contained any controls, and it does. However the handler still does not trigger.

```
        var jumpGroup = Page.FindControls<JumpButton>();
        foreach (var item in jumpGroup)
        {
            // This shows ID's
            Response.Write(item.ID);
        }

        jumpGroup.ForEach(uc => uc.HasVisited += new EventHandler(JumpGroup_HasVisited));
```

---

### UPDATE 2

Tracked the source of the problem but stil not sure why this doesn't work. IEnumerable extension method is at fault - when replaced by a foreach loop this works.

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> @this, Action<T> action)
    {
        @this.ThrowNull("@this");
        action.ThrowNull("action");

        foreach (T item in @this)
        {
            action(item);
            yield return item;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are the controls in `Controls` definitely of type `JumpButton`?

Comment: Don't you have `JumpButton`s nested in some other control, not directly in `Page`?

Comment: @Michal - Yes and no. For the purpose of the test No, in situe, Yes. I have an extension method that does a deep find, but I omitted it to keep focus on the main issue. However, when I use this code var jumpGroup = Page.FindControls<JumpButton>(); I definitely return controls - I have iterated through "jumpGroup" and listed the ID's

Comment: @Lews - Yes they are - see my response to Michal.

Comment: @MichalHosala - added an update

Comment: @LewsTherin - added an update

Comment: I just tested in Linqpad. Couldn't reproduce. Debug where HasVisited is invoked

Comment: @LewsTherin - I found the answer. It wasn't in the code directly, but an extension method .ForEach(), that wasn't carrying out acions. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual issue related to the IEnumerable.ForEach() extension method being used, which did not carry out the actions. Having amended the extension method, the code above now works.

Comment: OK so, IEnumerable has no ForEach extensions. Can you clarify whether it was something you wrote? (Appears to be)

Comment: Yes it was something I wrote - IEnumerable has no ForEach extension. The code posted about doesn't work becuase of the yield statement, which gives it a different purpose - remove it and voila, you have a working ForEach.